# Pandas TimeGrouper starting +1

Tags: pandas

My DataFrame looks like:

```
   Date   Count
2017-01-01  1
2017-01-02  2
2017-01-03  3
2017-01-04  4
2017-01-05  5
```

and I want to convert it starting 1 day later with the sum over the next to days to:

```
2017-01-01  5
2017-01-02  7
2017-01-03  9
2017-01-04  na
2017-01-05  na
```

Is this possible with additional parameters to TimeGrouper('2D') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html) and then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
print (df)
        Date  Count
0 2017-01-01      1
1 2017-01-02      2
2 2017-01-03      3
3 2017-01-04      4
4 2017-01-05      5

print (df.set_index('Date').rolling('2D').sum())
            Count
Date             
2017-01-01    1.0
2017-01-02    3.0
2017-01-03    5.0
2017-01-04    7.0
2017-01-05    9.0

df = df.set_index('Date').rolling('2D').sum().shift(-2).reset_index()
print (df)
        Date  Count
0 2017-01-01    5.0
1 2017-01-02    7.0
2 2017-01-03    9.0
3 2017-01-04    NaN
4 2017-01-05    NaN
```

Comment: rolling window needs to be an